# PHP - Mysql Set Table Name

Tags: php, mysqli

MySQLi line like this:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO '$this->dbTable' (url, name_surname, phone, city, category) VALUES('$contents[0]', '$contents[1]', '$contents[2]', '$contents[3]', '$contents[4]')";
```

Not:

```
$this->dbTable = 'crawler_data';
```

But above line does not work. MySQL does not accept. When I change line like this:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO crawler_data(url, name_surname, phone, city, category) VALUES('$contents[0]', '$contents[1]', '$contents[2]', '$contents[3]', '$contents[4]')";
```

It's working!

How can I set MySQL table name from out?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: thanx but i write this for test

Comment: Quotes are for strings, backticks for tables/columns, try `"INSERT INTO " . 
 $this->dbTable . " (` and or encapsulate that name in backticks. If that variable it not defined statically you also should use a whitelist to verify it is an acceptable value. Your other variables should be parameterized.

Comment: I'm also not clear what you mean by `from out`.

Comment: you can set $this->dbTable = 'crawler_data' before run your query

Comment: @chris85 you're perfect, thanx. you save my life!

Answer (score 0):

single or double quotes use for string.when we use '$this->table' it identify like string.change like this.

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO $this->dbTable (url, name_surname, phone, city, category) VALUES('$contents[0]', '$contents[1]', '$contents[2]', '$contents[3]', '$contents[4]')";
```

Comment: Do or Do Not, there is no "Try" padawan. A **good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.